# Adding functions to Audio object

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio

Trying to add a stop function to the Audio object in javascript like this

```
//Give the Audio object a stop function
Audio.prototype.stop = function()
{
this.pause();
this.currentTime = 0.0;
}
```

can be used like this

```
var aud = new Audio();
aud.src = 'background.ogg';
aud.play();
aud.stop();
```

Works in Google Chrome, but not in firefox. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an element with `new Audio` creates an element whose prototype is `HTMLAudioElement.prototype`.  Per spec this should be the same object as `Audio.prototype`, but I believe Firefox doesn't implement that part of WebIDL yet.

In any case, setting your stuff on `HTMLAudioElement.prototype` should work in both browsers, I would think.